# the installed date queried by power shell is null, which is a valid date listed by control panel

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to get all installed software on my computer with information like installed date, provider name and so on.
For example, I have installed "Everything". In windows control panel, the installed date of "Everything" is "2021/10/20".
[image]

However, when I use power shell to query information of "Everything", the installed date is null.
[image]

How can I get installed information of software which are listed in control panel with power shell script?

the powershell command is as below:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path ('HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*', 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*', 'HKCU:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*', 'HKCU:\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*') -ErrorAction Ignore | Where-Object DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName | Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -Descending
```

Comment: Which command you use to get output?

Comment: I pasted the command as above. The number and the Installed Date of programs are different with those shown in control panel.

Comment: Some softwares doesn't have registry entries for InstallDate . Please verify by navigating to the path of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\yoursoftwarename. If it is available and not returning in Powershell then it needs to be addressed. For ex: 7 Zip does not provide Installdate info.

Comment: is there any way to get the programs information shown in control panel?

Comment: Apart from this I can only think of app folder created date in ProgramFiles or ProgramFilesX64.